# Java Convert InputStream of XML to Document object always results in NULL

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse a XML string into `org.w3c.dom.Document` object.

I have looked at solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484921/how-to-convert-string-to-dom-document-object-in-java), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607327/how-to-create-a-xml-object-from-string-in-java) and a few other blogs that give a variation of the same solution. But the `Document` object's #Document variable is always null and nothing gets parsed.

Here is the XML file

```
 XMLMappingValidator v = new XMLMappingValidator("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
"<mapping>\n" +
"<container>\n" +
"<source-container>c:\\stem.csv</source-container>\n" +
"<source-type>CSV_FILE</source-type>\n" +
"<target-container>db</target-container>\n" +
"<target-type>MySQL_TABLE</target-type>\n" +
"</container>\n" +
"<entity>\n" +
"<source-entity>stem</source-entity>\n" +
"<target-entity>tbl_stem</target-entity>\n" +
"</entity>\n" +
"<attributes>\n" +
"<attribute>\n" +
"<datatype>SMALLINT</datatype>\n" +
"<source-attribute>id</source-attribute>\n" +
"<target-attribute>id</target-attribute>\n" +
"</attribute>\n" +
"<attribute>\n" +
"<datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>\n" +
"<source-attribute>name</source-attribute>\n" +
"<target-attribute>name</target-attribute>\n" +
"</attribute>\n" +
"<attribute>\n" +
"<datatype>TEXT</datatype>\n" +
"<source-attribute>body</source-attribute>\n" +
"<target-attribute>body</target-attribute>\n" +
"</attribute>\n" +
"<attribute>\n" +
"<datatype>DATETIME</datatype>\n" +
"<source-attribute>date</source-attribute>\n" +
"<target-attribute>date</target-attribute>\n" +
"</attribute>\n" +
"<attribute>\n" +
"<datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>\n" +
"<source-attribute>info</source-attribute>\n" +
"<target-attribute>info</target-attribute>\n" +
"</attribute>\n" +
"</attributes>\n" +
"</mapping>");
```

The constructor XMLMappingValidator object's code is as follows

```
public class XMLMappingValidator {
    private  Document xml;
    public XMLMappingValidator (String xmlString) throws 
            IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        this.xml = 
                builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));          
    }

    public Document getXML() {
        return xml;
    }
}
```

When I call **v.getXML().toString()** I get `[#document: null]`

Clearly, the parse is failing. But I don't understand why.

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clearly an exception is being thrown that you are ignoring. DocumentBuilder.parse() doesn't return  null. You're also contradicting yourself. Either getXML() returns null, in which case 'this.xml' is null, or 'this.xml' isn't null and is inspectable as you describe. Not both at the same time.

Comment: If the inspection says the document was read, the document was read.
Are you sure you're calling getXML() against the object which ran the parse? Are you sure the value you're getting back is really null, as opposed to just having a toString() that returns null?

Comment: you're right. I meant, getXML().toString() returns null. getXML() is not null. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Why are you using Document.toString() at all? It isn't obliged to have any specific behaviour. Try use the Document interface correctly.

Comment: I had recently used Nokogiri and I was confused as to why I was not able to getElementsByTag() from the document, which Nokogiri has... Nevertheless, I was able to use the Document object correctly. getChildNodes() method was crucial in doing what I needed to do.

Comment: @Anupam put it as the answer then. Or do you only want to help yourself?