# reading xml stored as a string in java

Tags: java, xml

The contents of my webpage is an XML file and I am saving this content in a string. I have to read the nodes of the XML file. How do I fetch the values of the nodes from this XML file?

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484921/how-to-convert-string-to-dom-document-object-in-java

Comment: I tried to save the contents in an XML file and then read from it as a normal XML file, but I dont want to create a new file. Is there any way I can do this without saving the contents in a temp xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java?rq=1

Comment: Most XML parsers can read from a string: xpp3, commons digester, xerces (and many more).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Document

[In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file)

```
public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    return builder.parse(is);
```

}