# Conversion of String to w3c.Document returns null Document

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am getting **xml response** from 3rd party API via feign client which I am collecting in String and then trying to convert the String into **org.w3c.dom.Document**.

I have searched for String to Document conversion code and came across below links.

1. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/parse-string-to-xml-dom/
2. [How to convert String to DOM Document object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484921/how-to-convert-string-to-dom-document-object-in-java/44845803)
3. https://www.journaldev.com/1237/java-convert-string-to-xml-document-and-xml-document-to-string

problem is my conversion logic is not working and Document = null.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String xmlStr = "<Emp id=\"1\"><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age>\n"+
                "<role>Developer</role><gen>Male</gen></Emp>";

        Document doc = convertStringToXMLDocument(xmlStr);
 }
 private static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(String xmlString)
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have tried debugging code of **builder.parse()** but not able to find why document conversion is null.

```
Output: doc: "[#document : null]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Document doc` is not null. The "[#document : null]" only is the output from `xerces` `NodeImpl.toString`. It means [element name or element type : element value]. So [#document : null] means document element : no direct value. That's true because only text nodes have direct values.

You will be able to iterate over the `Document doc` and to get all the child nodes (element nodes as well as text nodes) as follows:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class DocumentBuilderTest {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String xmlStr = "<Emp id=\"1\"><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age>\n"+
                        "<role>Developer</role><gen>Male</gen></Emp>";
  Document doc = convertStringToXMLDocument(xmlStr);
  printAllChildNodes(doc);
 }
 
 public static void printAllChildNodes(Node node) {
  System.out.println(node);

  NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
   Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
   printAllChildNodes(currentNode);
  }
 }
 
 private static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(String xmlString) {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder;
  try {
   builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
   return doc;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
 }
}
```

This prints:

```
[#document: null]
[Emp: null]
[name: null]
[#text: Pankaj]
[age: null]
[#text: 25]
[#text:
]
[role: null]
[#text: Developer]
[gen: null]
[#text: Male]
```